# What is the structure and function of chromosomes during interphase?

Tags: homework, chromosome

Ok, it seems to be easy but I have probably ignored something by accident.

Interphase is the phase where things are growing and the preparation for cell division happens. Its stages G1, S and G2. DNA replication in S stage. So the DNA in some chromosomes must have the pieces of information about how to do the DNA replication. - I am not sure  about thing.

I would say to the part: structure that chromosomes are diploid at the given stage. - It does not feel right anyway.

**What would you answer to the main question?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the DNA in some chromosomes must have the pieces of information about how to do the DNA replication. - I am not sure about thing.

Genomes contain what is called the "origin of replication" - specific sequences in the DNA that tell DNA polymerase where to bind and to initiate replication.

As for your main question, I'm a little confused as to what you're asking. In a general sense, chromosomes function as carriers of genetic information. In eukaryotes, nuclear DNA is organized in the nucleus on linear chromosomes which carry most of the genetic information an organism needs to survive. In bacteria, the chromosome is a circular piece of DNA. In eukaryotes, the chromosome is also bound by histone proteins, which serves to regulate expression of certain genes and to help anchor the chromosomes to the inner nuclear membrane.